# Getting list of images from a folder in image.xcassets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a folder in image.xcassets which has more than 50 images for both iPhone and iPad.
I don't want to hard code all the names programatically. Can I get the list of images in that folder in an NSArray?

Comment: If you don't find any solution, Do one thing give name images to 1...50 and after that take image using loop

Comment: where u able to get the images name?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this fully answers your question, but should you normally do this with the method

`- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:(NSURL *)url includingPropertiesForKeys:(NSArray *)keys options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions)mask error:(NSError **)error` ?

This is a code snippet from a program I wrote to get all the images from a directory:

```
-(void)getContentOfImageDirectory
{
    //Emptying the image directory content array
    [_imageDirectoryContent removeAllObjects];

    //Using NSFileManager to load the content of the image directory in a temporary array
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *tempArray = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtURL: _imageDirectory includingPropertiesForKeys: _imageProperties options: NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsPackageDescendants error: nil];

    //Copy the temporary array into the imageDirectoryContent before returning the NSMutableArray imageDirectoryContent
    [_imageDirectoryContent addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
}
```

The variable `_imageProperties` is just an array of "common file system resource keys" as Apple calls them. The variable `_imageDirectory` is the URL from which you want to get the files. 
hope this helps.

Comment: I know this. Please read my question clearly. I want to get images from image.xcassets which means asset catalog. It is not any directory

Comment: I'm sorry to annoy you, but if I use the URL file///User/<Your Userid>/your file path to the program/Images.xcassets/ I get the content of that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to annoy you and misunderstood your question. However, if I use the URL `file///User/<Your Userid>/your file path to the program/Images.xcassets/` I get the content of that directory.

On the other hand if I use `URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask` 
and then

```
URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Your Application container/Contents/Resources"
```

*I can read all the image files of any fully compiled and operational application.* I'm not aware of determining the application's resource folder in any other way.

This is a code snippet for accessing the resources directory of the Windows 7 applications folder from parallels.

```
    -(id)initWithStartURL
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        //Initiating the file manager
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        //Getting the applications directory
        NSArray *listOfURLs = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
        if([listOfURLs count] >= 1)
        {
            _tempDirectory = [listOfURLs objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        _imageDirectory = [_tempDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Windows 7 Applications.app/Contents/Resources"];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Just added the method -(id)initWithStartURL